# .net frame work 3.5 not showing in feature list window server 2008 sp2.

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, windows-server-2008, .net-3.5

.net frame work 3.5 not showing in feature list window server 2008 sp2.  How to add .net framework 3.5 in feature list of window server 2008 sp2

Comment: You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

Comment: i downloaded and install it  after installation and restart it does not showing in feature list in server manager

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista should only ship with .NET Framework 3.0, which means if you installed 3.5 it would appear solely in Control Panel | Programs like any other programs.